# How to save as .txt in vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am looking to have my Macro save a new sheet that i created as a .txt file. this is the code i have so far.

```
Sub Move()  
'  
' Move Macro  
'  
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m  
'  
Sheets("Sheet1").Select  
Range("A1").Select  
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select  
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select  
Selection.Copy  
Workbooks.Add  
ActiveSheet.Paste  

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="e:" & _
"HDR" + Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDDhhmmss") & ".txt"

End Sub
```

That includes my macro. I am having trouble with the last part where it saves as a .txt file.
I am currently getting a bunch of crap on my .txt file, here is an example,
"PK     ! !}ñU{  Š   [Content_Types].xml ¢(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ÌTÝNÂ0¾7ñ–Þš­€‰1†Á…â¥’ˆPÚ3¶ÐµMOÁñöž•Ÿ¨".
Any help would be great.

Comment: FYI, you cannot save multiple sheets as a text file. If you try it manually, you will be warned that only the active sheet will be saved.

Comment: LOL the sub is called `Move()` but it only makes a copy of the data into a text file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Manually changing the extension of the file name does not actually change the file type.  The `SaveAs` method takes a file type argument.  The code you want is

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="e:" & "HDR" + Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDDhhmmss") _
& ".txt", FileFormat:= xlTextWindows
```

Doing a search from within Excel help for `XlFileFormat` will get you (almost) the full list of possible file formats, including 6 text formats, and 4 CSV formats.

Comment: In this method, a " char will be added to the beginning and end of each line

Answer (score 2):

Adding txt to the name does not automatically encode the word document into plain text format.

Instead attempt

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="e:" & _
"HDR" + Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDDhhmmss") & ".txt", FileFormat:=wdFormatText, Encoding:=1252
```

Comment: Wow this was 6 years ago. I'm sure it worked at the time, perhaps the encoding or fileformat has changed.

Answer (score 2):

The ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs method adds double quote to the beginning and end of every line in the file.

This method parses each line from a given range and transforms it into a CSV file:

```
Sub SaveSheetToCSVorTXT()
    Dim xFileName As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim DelimChar As String

    DelimChar = "," 'The delimitation character to be used in the saved file. This will be used to separate cells in the same row

    xFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(ActiveSheet.Name, "CSV File (*.csv), *.csv, Text File (*.txt), *.txt")
    If xFileName = False Then Exit Sub

    If Dir(xFileName) <> "" Then
        If MsgBox("File '" & xFileName & "' already existe.  Overwrite?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation) <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
        Kill xFileName
    End If

    Open xFileName For Output As #1
    'Save range contents. Examples of ranges:
    'Set rng = Activesheet.Range("A1:D4")   'A rectangle between 2 cells
    'Set rng = Activesheet.columns(1)       'An entire column
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B14").CurrentRegion   'The "region" from a cell. This is the same as pressing CTRL+T on the selected cell

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & DelimChar) & rng.Cells(i, j)
        Next j
        Print #1, lineText
    Next i
    Close #1

    MsgBox "File saved!"
End Sub
```