# VBA saving tab as text file causing 1004 error for one tab but not another?

Tags: excel, vba, text-files, save-as

I'm trying to save different tabs of my workbook as text files to a specified location. So far I have it so that it works for one tab, but not the second (the second says "runtime error 1004: method 'saveas' of object '_workbook' failed").
The code is as follows:

```
Dim filepath As String

'fileName = Worksheets("journal").Range("l10").Value
filepath = "s:\" & Worksheets("journal").Range("l8")

Sheets("journal").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=filepath & Range("l10"), _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

Sheets("header").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=filepath & Worksheets("journal").Range("l10") & "_head", _
    FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

Sheets("detail").Select    
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=filepath & Worksheets("journal").Range("l10") & "_det", _
    FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
```

The "workbook" & "header" files save as intended, but the error occurs when the "detail" tries to save, even though to me it looks the same as the "header" code.

I'm quite new to this and I feel I'm missing something quite obvious, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: Take a close look on how you declare filepath the first time, and make use of it the second and third time. Is this intended behaviour. (Taking values of multiple cells?)

Comment: As soon as you use SaveAs, the active workbook change to the new saved workbook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save as .txt in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151021/how-to-save-as-txt-in-vba)